# Json.Encode() Doesnt Recognize objects, sets them as a string FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, request

Im trying to sent and HTTP post request to the backend of my aplication, the problem is when I set the body of the request it is set as a string. Currently im working with the class TimeSlot.

```
class TimeSlot {
final String id;
final int year;
final int month;
final int day;
final int hour;

TimeSlot(
  {this.year = 0,
  this.day = 0,
  this.hour = 0,
  this.month = 0,
  required this.id});

Map toJson() => {'year': year, 'month': month, 'day': day, 'hour': hour};
}
```

and the method

```
Future<Tutorship> sendNewTutorship(
  List<TimeSlot> timeSlots,
  String description,
  String tutorshipId,
  String courseId,
  String studentId) async {
var slots = jsonEncode(timeSlots);

var body = jsonEncode({
  'tutorshipId': tutorshipId,
  'studentId': studentId,
  'courseId': courseId,
  'availableSlots': slots,
  'description': description
});

print(body);

Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};

final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(Strings.serviceUrl + '/tutorships'),
  headers: headers,
  body: body,
);

if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  return Tutorship.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
} else {
  throw Exception('Could not create the tutorship');
} 
}
```

The print method shows me how the TimeSlot list is parsed, which is what I want:
**[{"year":2021,"month":8,"day":8,"hour":9}]**

But when is set into the body request, it changes to a string like this:

**"[{\"year\":2021,\"month\":8,\"day\":11,\"hour\":9}]"**

It is any way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encodings slots twice times and you are not convering timeslots to a list of maps so change

```
var slots = jsonEncode(timeSlots);

var body = jsonEncode({
  'tutorshipId': tutorshipId,
  'studentId': studentId,
  'courseId': courseId,
  'availableSlots': slots,
  'description': description
});
```

to this

(also prefer final keyword for defining immutable variables)

```
final body = jsonEncode({
  'tutorshipId': tutorshipId,
  'studentId': studentId,
  'courseId': courseId,
  'availableSlots': timeSlots.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList(),
  'description': description
});
```

An explanation about Jsons:

- Json Encoding means converting maps or lists to a string and we name this string a Json
- Json Decoding means converting a Json(a string) to what it was before encoding it